# Difference between "var", "let" and "const"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, local-variables, language-features, let

ECMAScript 6 introduced two new ways of declaring variables: [the `let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [the `const` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const). How are they different from the `var` keyword?

Comment: @JimStewart In what way is that Q&A better than mine? Questions should be closed as duplicate of questions which have better answers, and IMO my answer is much better. See [Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938/3853934)

Comment: **Note**: this is an attempt to create a better canonical questions explaining the differences between "var", "let" and "const". Please don't close it as a duplicate of [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/762011/3853934) before reading the Meta questions: [User refusing to correct misinformation in their popular answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338376/3853934) and [Canonical question explaining differences between “var”, “let” and “const” in JavaScript](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338663/3853934).